# Return records where search data does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a view containing data from tables employees and courses. Using this view i can easily find which courses every employee has been on, I however would like to know (depending on employees job title) what compulsory course they haven't been on. For example, all new employees with the job title 'cle' are required to go on a data protection course ('data'). How do I return all employees with job title 'cle' that haven't been on the 'data' course?

I think I need something similar to '!= 'data'' where it actually returns all employees who have a record of 'cle' but don't have a record of 'data' against them and disregards all the others.

I hope someone understands this?

Comment: Provide table structure for this type of question plz. And `!= data` becomes `<> data` or `NOT EXIST` in SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title suggests the answer, use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM dbo.Employee e
WHERE [job title] = 'cle'
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Courses c
    WHERE c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
     AND  c.ProtectionCourse = 'data'
)
```

Note that i've presumed all table and column. But you should get the idea.

Comment: vielen dank. Had to change a few things with my initial view but got it working now

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    employee e
LEFT JOIN
    courses c
ON  
    e.employeeID = c.employeeID and
    c.courseType = 'data'
WHERE
    e.jobTitle = 'cle' and
    c.employeeID is null
```

You will need to check column names etc, as you haven't given us the table structure, but you get the idea.

Comment: The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` syntax is less efficient than `NOT EXISTS` in sql-server since it needs to join all rows, then eliminate the matches. Also, if the join-column is nullable  you would even get unpredicatable results, because there is no way to differentiate between a row that doesn't exist and a row that does exist but where that column is NULL. http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: Hmm, interesting that it is less performant. Providing an appropriate column is chosen, the results will be predictable. I do disagree with the article that the `LEFT JOIN` syntax is less readable, though that is simply down to personal taste.